# Scala Type matching function inside a trait body

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, traits

I'm new to Scala and working through this book ([Function Programming in Scala](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala)). One of the exercises involves replicating the `Option` trait and its functions. However I'm having a problem compiling my solution in the REPL.

```
sealed trait Nullable[+A] {

    def get[B >: A](default: => B) : B = this match {
        case Value(v) => v
        case Null => default
    }
}
case class Value[+A](value: A) extends Nullable[A]
case object Null extends Nullable[Nothing]
```

REPL error details:

```
error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
found   : Value[A(in class Value)]
required: Nullable[A(in trait Nullable)]
             case Value(v) => v

error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
found   : Null.type
required: Nullable[A]
             case Null => default
```

Based on those errors I have a nagging feeling that the compiler can't infer that the type of `this` (being pattern matched on) is a `Nullable`.

I've tried this block of code on this online [Scala utility](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_scala_online.php) and it seems to compile and run. The only difference I can see is that the online tool is using Scala version 2.10.3 and I'm running 2.11.7

So I'm not sure if this is environmental or if I need to help the Scala compiler here. I have also tried to compile the [answer](https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/errorhandling/Option.scala) from the book's authors and I get the same errors.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: When using the repl use `:paste` to enter multiline scala code, that should fix your issue.

Comment: Yep, @Noah is right.  REPL (2.11.7) compiles it just fine when inserted as a block (i.e. `:pa`).

Comment: Does this still apply if I'm using the `:load` command to load a .scala file?

Comment: @Noah never mind. Just tried it and it works! Cheers for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting an answer in case someone else has a similar issue.

Use the REPL `:paste` command to load the .scala file, instead of the `:load` command.

Thank you to @noah and @jwvh for the help.